# Как считать массив чисел в c++?

Tags: c++

недавно начал учить с++, до этого изучал python, столкнулся с таким вопросом.
Как правильно в c++ считать строку, состоящую из целых чисел, количество которых мы не можем знать?
в python,for example, было бы так:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

как такую операцию записать на с++?

Comment: Объявить динамический массив и наполнять его вычитывая целые из input stream в цикле.

Comment: @VTT Это просто если количество чисел известно. Если нет - то немного сложнее...

Answer (score 1):

Сначала считываем строку целиком через `getline`, а потом достаем из нее числа с помощью `istringstream`.

Вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::istringstream stream(str);

    std::vector<int> vec;
    int x;
    while (stream >> x)
        vec.push_back(x);

    if (!stream.eof())
    {
        std::cout << "Строка имеет неправильный формат.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (int x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Если вам нравятся <s>понты</s> веяния *modern C++*™, то цикл `while` можно заменить на `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(stream), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(vec));`.